# What i'm doing wrong comparing this two timestamps?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm comparing two timestamps in angular with an unexpected result. This is my code:

```
public isAuthenticated(): boolean {

    const token = localStorage.getItem('Fakelife');
    const lifetime = new Date().getTime();
    const result = lifetime - token;
    const hoursDiff = result / (3600 * 1000);
    if ( hoursDiff > 3600 ) {
        //60 minutes were passed from start
        console.log('not expired');
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log('expired');
        return false;
    }
}
```

result of token is = 1557167443251
result of lifetime is = 1557167505672
Result of hoursDiff is 0.02560138888888889

As you see, i just want to compare if one hour has been passed. What i'm doing wrong?

always returns console.log('expired');

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It looks like hoursDiff has the value in hours and not seconds, since you are dividing by `3600*1000`, so you really need to say `hoursDiff>1`.

Comment: imho your result is correct - didnt calculate it myself but it shows that less than an hour has been passed yet

Comment: Local storage can only store strings, you should really parse it back into a number on retrieval. Even if JavaScript has ridiculously loose automatic type conversions.

Comment: By the way, with this code, always returns console.log('expired');.

Comment: if hoursDiff is smaller than a certain value then it's not expired not opposite

Comment: Thanks. You are right. The correct comparison is: if ( hoursDiff < 0.00277778 ) -> This will compare if the expired time is higher than 10 seconds, and works as expected so as @inquizitive said, 1 should be fine for one hour. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, here is the code that should work, even though it might not be logically the best way!

```
public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('Fakelife'); //this returns a string
    const lifetime = new Date().getTime(); // current time in millis
    const result = lifetime - token; //difference between two times in millis
    const hoursDiff = result / (1000); //difference between two times in seconds
    if ( hoursDiff < 3600 ) { // if less than 3600 seconds, token is not expired
        //3600 seconds have not passed
        console.log('not expired');
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log('expired');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more condensed way to do it.

```
public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
  return (new Date().getTime() - (1000 * 60 * 60) < parseInt(localStorage.getItem('Fakelife')));
}
```